# Acentuação com Resource em Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resources

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC onde uso resource, mas estou tendo problemas com acentuação outros caracteres especiais.

Exemplo:

 Tenho o seguinte Resource:

```
Name                   |  Value
MSG_SESSAO_EXPIRADA    |  *Sessão expirada!
```

Em minha View tenho:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      alert('@Resources.MSG_SESSAO_EXPIRADA');
</script>
```

O obtido é:

```
Sess&#227;o expirada!
```

Ou seja, ele não consegue exibir o `ã`, mas faz a conversão.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui usando uma alternativa interessante:

Em meu `alert` usei o método [Raw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) do [HTML Helper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx) e funcionou perfeitamente.

```
alert('@Html.Raw(Resources.MSG_SESSAO_EXPIRADA)');
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu código no html tem `charset="utf-8"`. O seu arquivo resource deve estar com formato UTF-8 também, senão pode dar divergência no charset.

Uma alternativa é escrever o seu Resource, convertendo os caracteres necessários utilizando a relação de caracteres na [Tabela Unicode/UTF8](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

**Exemplo:** No lugar de `ã` escreva `\u00E3`

Comment: Bem, isso só tem acontecido ao colocar o resource diretamente no Javascript, mas quando uso no HTML funciona perfeitamente.